# MySQL won't start when upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

Today I upgraded from Leopard (10.5) to Snow Leopard (10.6). After upgrading MySQL wouldn't start so I downloaded MySQL 5.5.8 (64bit) dmg. I installed MySQL, Startup Item and PrefPane.

After this I tried to 'Start mySQL Server' from System Preferences but nothing happens. The Server instance remains at stopped.

Does anybody have any advice for fixing this and getting MySQL up and running again?

I'm not a developer so I'm not even sure where to begin when trying to debug this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by opening [Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28Mac_OS_X%29) and monitoring the System Log while attempting to start MySQL. And also [mysql error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html), wherever you have configure it to be.

Comment: Thanks Remus.28/12/2010 12:18:16 [0x0-0x4e04e].com.apple.systempreferences[2662] /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 256: my_print_defaults: command not found

Comment: Couldn't find the mysql error log anywhere. If I open usr/local the folder "mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64" is definitely there

Comment: Look into that mysql.server script and see what is on line 256 and why does it expect my_print_defaults to be in the path. As an alternative, you can give MAMP a try, since that comes with a full stack (apache, php, mysql) preconfigured in a Mac package.

Comment: This fixed it in the end http://www.artin.org/geekblog/2010/12/installing-mysql-5-5-8-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/ had to set basedir and datadir